# Multiple programs in supervisor

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, supervisord, systemctl

I'm deploying a Django app in a virtual environment and I'm using supervisor for the app itself and some Celery tasks. When my `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/project` is like this:

```
[program:botApp]
command = /home/ubuntu/gunicorn_start.bash;
user = ubuntu;
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log;
redirect_stderr = true;
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;
```

it works fine, I do `sudo systemctl restart supervisor` and I can see it running properly, but when I add my second program in the same configuration file like this:

```
[program:botApp]
command = /home/ubuntu/gunicorn_start.bash;
user = ubuntu;
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log;
redirect_stderr = true;
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8;

[program:worker]
command=/home/ubuntu/django_env/bin/celery -A botApp worker -l info;
user=ubuntu;
numprocs=1;
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celeryworker.log;
redirect_stderr = true;
autostart=true;
autorestart=true;
startsecs=10;
stopwaitsecs = 600 ;
killasgroup=true;
priority=998;
```

it throws the following error:

```
● supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX


Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-09-04 08:09:26 UTC; 12s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 21931 ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21925 ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 21925 (code=exited, status=2)

Sep 04 08:09:26 ip-172-31-45-13 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 04 08:09:26 ip-172-31-45-13 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried changing the second program to be the same as the first one with different name and log file and it throws the same error. Do I need to do something extra for using 2 programs with supervisor? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was asked over a year ago, it seems doubtful we'll ever receive the answers to these questions, but the following pieces of information would have been helpful:

- what Linux distribution and version are (or were) you using; *e.g.*, Ubuntu 18.04, CentOS 7, etc.?
- did you look at the logs generated by systemd? (`journalctl -xu supervisord`)

  - what, if any, messages did they contain?
- did you look at the individual log files generated by your two supervisord services (*e.g.*, `/home/ubuntu/logs/celeryworker.log`)?

  - what, if any, messages did *they* contain?

My gut feel is that the output of `journalctl -xu supervisord` will tell you what you need to know. Or at least move you a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:

`sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl update`

and then restart your supervisorctl